# Trouble in installing loopback on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, loopbackjs

After running the command :

`npm install -g loopback-cli`

I am getting this output:

```
C:\>npm install -g loopback-cli npm WARN deprecated swagger-ui@2.2.10:
   No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-ui@3. 
D:\project\IOT-KT\infra\nfr-iot-md\testSpecs\nodejs\node_modules\windows-build-tools\lb
D:\project\IOT-KT\infra\nfr-iot-md\testSpecs\nodejs\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\loopback-cli\bin\loopback-cli.js
loopback-cli@5.0.2 updated 1 package in 115.326s

C:\>lb 'lb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>lb4 'lb4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

But if go to location : D:\project\IOT-KT\infra\nfr-iot-md\testSpecs\nodejs\node_modules\windows-build-tools

and run lb command it is working, I created a project but then I was not able to create model because lb was not available in the project folder.

I am new to node js and learning loopback, please help me install loopback cli correctly on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As after watching the error it's saying that you need to upgrade to `swagger-ui@3` that might be reason.

Once above not worked then try below methods:

**Steps:**

1. delete node_modules
2. delete package_lock.json
3. clear cache either by this  (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm) and
   (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache) or this way

   run `npm cache clean --force`
4. Then run `npm install`

If the dependencies at global level then you need to [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) globally too

```
npm update -g
```

From error it also looks you also need to set the PATH too or the path you set need to modify.

Add PATH in Environment Variables: `(C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm)`

then try to install your desired packages.

Comment: I used "npm config get prefix" to get the current path, which in my case was wrong, then using command "npm config set prefix C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm" I set the prefix path and after this when I executed "npm install -g loopback-cli" and ran lb command, it worked like charm . I don't know why my question is negative marked

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me for Windows error:
C:>lb4 'lb4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Update your Environmental Variables, Go to:

Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Add PATH in Environment Variables: (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm)